# Problems of waiting time

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have always a hard time solving problems of waiting time. Here is an exercise with uniform distribution, but I hope you can help me to understand the reasoning at the basis of this type of problems. Thanks in advance.

---

The bus that connect NYC's station to the city centre previews departures at 9:30 and at 10:00. The train from Albany arrives, according to the timetable, at NYC at 9:00. However it's always late and it arrives at the station at a random time $X$, uniformly distributed between 9:00 and 10:00. Professor is on the train. Let $T$ the time that professor will have to wait to take the bus.

- 1) Find the distribution of $T$.
- 2) Calculate the probability that professor has to wait less than $10$ minutes.
- 3) Find the mean and the variance of $T$.
- 4) We assume that the departure time of the first bus is a random variable with uniform distribution between 9:00 and 10:00, and that the second bus starts surely at 10:00. Find the probability that, in this situation, professor has to wait less than $10$ minutes.

The only point that maybe I solved is the second, but failed to formalize anything. I only observed that $10$ minutes are $\frac{1}{6}$ of an hour, so: $\mathbb{P}(T<0)=1-\mathbb{P}(T\geq 10)=1-\mathbb{P}(-10>T>10)=1-(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6})=\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: What's the difficulty you are facing? Can you solve, for example, the first part?

Comment: @MattiP. I know that $\mathbb{P}(T\geq 0)=\mathbb{P}[(T=0) \cup (T>0)]=\mathbb{P}(T=0)+\mathbb{P}(T>0)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq ?)+\mathbb{P}(X\leq t+?)$ but I don't understand what is the value of $?$. After this I'll use the CDF of the uniform.

Answer (score 1):

1)/2) To find the distribution of $T$, you want to find $\mathbb{P}(T < t)$, but if I were writing these problems I'd have put 2) first. So imagine $t = 10$. What is the probability that you wait less than 10 minutes. Well there are two ways this can happen. One of the is you arrive between 9.20 and 9.30. The other is you arrive between 9.50 and 10.00. Since arrival time is uniform, can you now work it out now? Then take a general $t > 0$ and do the same logic, noting that you cannot actually wait more than 30 minutes ever.

Comment: Thank you. Have you seen my attempt to solve the second point? I just wrote $\mathbb{P}(T<t),t=10$, but I don't know if the solution is right. Instead, for the first point I would do $\mathbb{P}(T\geq 0)=\mathbb{P}(T=0)+\mathbb{P}(T>0)$, with $\mathbb{P}(T=0)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq 30)=\int_{0}^{30}f_X(x)dx$.

Comment: Why are you considering things such as $T < 0$?? There cannot be any negative waiting times. I've tried to explain an approach based on the fact that
$$
\{ T \leq 10\} = \{9.20 \leq X \leq 9.30\} \cup \{9.50 \leq X \leq 10.00\}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I'm sorry if I'm answering only now. Ok, I understood your approach but… How do I calculate these probabilities?

Comment: You know that $X$ has a uniform distribution. If you know what that means, then it is easy to calculate these probabilities. If you do not know what that means, then you cannot approach this problem really.